# Why am I not able to detect if the file exist with this linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following code to detect if a file exist:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="/home/$USER/MyShellScripts/sample.txt"
if [ -e '$VAR' ]
        then
                echo "$VAR exist"
        else
                echo "the file $VAR doesn't exist!"
fi

if [ -x '$VAR' ]
        then
                echo "You have permissions to execute the file $VAR"
        else
                echo "You do not have permissions to execute the file $VAR"
fi
```

When I apply the ls command on the specified directory I see:

```
MyLAPTOP:~/MyShellScripts$ ls
exercise_4.sh  exercise_4Original.sh  first.sh  sample.txt  second.sh
```

So, if the file exists in the specified directory, why it is not detected? Below the script output:

```
MyLAPTOP:~/MyShellScripts$ ./exercise_4.sh
the file /home/username/MyShellScripts/sample.txt doesn't exist!
You do not have permissions to execute the file /home/username/MyShellScripts/sample.txt
```

Comment: Because you're using single quotes (`'$VAR'`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13799789/608639), [How to echo variable inside single quotes using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29351101/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` means do not expand variables.

So this script checks file named '~/MyShellScripts/$VAR'. Not '"/home//MyShellScripts/sample.txt"'

Test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="Test"
echo $VAR
echo "$VAR"
echo '$VAR'
```

Result:

```
$ ./Test.sh
Test
Test
$VAR
```

Answer (score 4):

Thats because you are using `'$VAR'` instead of `"$VAR"` in your `if`.
Try `"$VAR"` instead.
The `$VAR` within single quotes (`''`) will be interpreted as an normal string and not resolved to your variable.

To see the difference, try the following:

```
input          output
-------------- --------------------------------------------------
echo "$VAR"    /home/<your_username>/MyShellScripts/sample.txt
echo '$VAR'    $VAR
```